# Copy users Radio Selection to another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, copy, radio-button

I have 2+ Registration forms at times on my site. They have the exact same fields so it gets crazy to have to ask the user to keep entering in their information.

I have added a checkbox that allows a user to click and it will copy their form1 results (field by field using .val() instead of the clone() function which did more harm then good), too all other forms that appear on the page.

I have a mix of text, select drop downs, and radio buttons in the form. I can get the text and select drop downs to copy over to the others, but I can't seem to do it for the radio buttons.

The following code is an example of how I am doing it for the 1 text field and 1 select box, since I don't want to bog you guys down with all the code.

```
$('#sameaddress').click(function () {
    if ($('#sameaddress').attr('checked')) {
        //Text Field
        $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-student-id input').val($('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-student-id input').val());
        //Select box
        var jobtype = $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-job-type option:selected').val();
        $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-job-type option[value=' + jobtype + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    };
});
```

So you can see how I am doing this, but I am looking for some help to do the same with radio selections. Any thoughts? If I can remain in the same function that would be great, since I have about 3-4 radio questions to copy over and there must be a way.

**UPDATE**
Adding in a larger chunk of code because I thought it would help maybe make this make more sense (and yes this code does work). Again, I tried to target the radio button by using the same exact format as I did for the regular text inputs but that didn't work.

```
// First we need to give the forms some classes we can actually work with.
$("#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration_information fieldset").addClass("registration-form");
$("#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration_information fieldset:first").removeClass("registration-form").addClass("registration-form-first");

// Now I add in the check box to use, doing this hear so I can specify that I want it to only show on the first form
$('<div><label for="sameaddress">Use Same Information on additional Registration forms (If applicable)</label><input type="checkbox" name="sameaddress" id="sameaddress" /></div>').insertAfter('.registration_information fieldset:first .field-name-field-how-did-you-hear-about-thi');

// Now lets copy everything to other forms
$('#sameaddress').click(function(){
if($('#sameaddress').attr('checked')){
    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-student-id input').val($('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-student-id input').val());
    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-first-name input').val($('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-first-name input').val());

    // Copy each line as shown above for each of your text inputs, replacing the parent .field-name-field value for each.

    // For the select boxes see below
    var prefix = $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-prefix option:selected').val();
               $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-prefix option[value=' + prefix + ']').attr('selected','selected');
    var jobtype = $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form-first .field-name-field-job-type option:selected').val();
                      $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-job-type option[value=' + jobtype + ']').attr('selected','selected');    

} else { 

    //Clear on uncheck

    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-student-id input').val("");
    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-first-name input').val("");
    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-prefix option[value=Nothing]').attr('selected','selected');
    $('#commerce-checkout-form-registration .registration-form .field-name-field-job-type option[value=Nothing]').attr('selected','selected');
};

});
```

Comment: for radio you can do as you did for the text using `val()`.. but you sure this code is working.. cause i doubt it is..

Comment: Anyone? @bipen 's suggestion didn't work. And yes the script is working fine, see UPDATE in original Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh I went ahead and just changed the radio buttons to select lists instead which work without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe somebody needs the solution, like I did.

Let's say you have this:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" value="a" />Option One<br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" value="b" />Option Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" value="c" />Option Three<br />
```

To get the selected value from a radio button, you use:

```
$('input[name="myRadioButton"]:checked').val();
```

To set the second value, for example, you use:

```
$('input[name="myRadioButton"][value="b"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If you have two radio buttons, with exactly the same values as each other, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="firstRadio" value="a" />Option One<br />
<input type="radio" name="firstRadio" value="b" />Option Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="firstRadio" value="c" />Option Three<br />

<input type="radio" name="secondRadio" value="a" />Option One<br />
<input type="radio" name="secondRadio" value="b" />Option Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="secondRadio" value="c" />Option Three<br />
```

you would just join the two function, using something like this:

```
$('input[name="firstRadio"][value="'+$('input[name="secondRadio"]:checked').val()+'"]')
    .prop('checked', true);
```

This copies the selected option from secondRadio into firstRadio.